# Retrieve Google authenticated user data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) of Firebase it states

> You **create a new user** in your Firebase project by calling the
>   createUserWithEmailAndPassword method or **by signing in a user for the
>   first time using a federated identity provider**, such as Google Sign-In
>   or Facebook Login.

I'm using [`react-native-google-signin` library](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin) to sign in and after one day of thinkering with it it's finally working. I can see the logged-in user data coming in after a successful login.

But in the Firebase Console, under Authentication i don't see any new user added.

Of course i guess one way of handling it would be something that looks like

```
GoogleSignin.signIn().then(user => {
    // if the user doesn't already exist        
    firebase.auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, randomPassowrd);
})
```

But this feels like a workaround and the doc says that you can create a new user in firebase by signing in with google... so why this is not happening automatically?

This is my current implementation, i think this is the simplest possible way, as i sayd login is successful and data are flowing in.

```js
GoogleSignin
    .configure({
        iosClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID
    })
    .then(() => {
         GoogleSignin
        .signIn()
        .then((user) => {
            console.log('user ->', user);
            dispatch(LoginSuccessAction(user))
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch(LoginFailAction())
        })
        .done();
    })
    .done();
```

Comment: If you sign a user into Firebase Authentication with Google (or any other provider), they will show up in the [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/users). If that doesn't happen for your app, share the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i added the code example

Comment: The code you shared doesn't sign the user in to Firebase, so they indeed won't show up in the Firebase console (nor will they have authenticated access to Firebase services). You're missing a call to `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)` as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-handle-the-sign-in-flow-manually

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ok i was super dumb, thank you for helping, please post it as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted! The whole OAuth flow is always a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sign a user into Firebase Authentication with Google (or any other provider), they will show up in the [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/users).

The code you shared doesn't sign the user in to Firebase, so they indeed won't show up in the Firebase console (nor will they have authenticated access to Firebase services). You're missing a call to `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)` as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-handle-the-sign-in-flow-manually